# How does text area encode and decode?

Tags: html, encoding, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco editor for a web editor.

The problem is that I got a string (a file encoded in UTF-16 LE, read by Java backend) and Monaco couldn't show it as expected. For example:

[image]
But when I copy the disordered string into `textarea` it works, and when I copy it back to the editor it still works. For example:

[image]

So my question is how does html text area encode and decode string? What happened during the copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get your OS default encoding type and encoding as utf-8 type.
new String(inputStr.getBytes(),"utf-8");  

new String(inputStr.getBytes("utf-8"),"utf-8");
new String(inputStr.getBytes("utf-8"),"gbk");
```